# Is it possible to automatically create a dependency injection scope matching the lifetime of a Blazor component?

Tags: razor, dependency-injection, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am wondering if there is something similar to this in Blazor:

```
@injectScoped IMyService Service
```

So the injected instance will be created when the component is created and destroyed when the component is destroyed.

Any child component using the same `@injectScoped` directive will receive the parent's instance, not the singleton (global) one created at the root.

I am still searching for how to achieve that in a Blazor Webassembly app.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.owningcomponentbase?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OwningComponentBase` or `OwningComponentBase<>`

```cs
@inherits OwningComponentBase<SomeService>
<h3>SomeComponent</h3>

@code {
    SomeService myService => base.Service;
}
```

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.owningcomponentbase?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: It seems to be exactly what I am looking for. I gave it a quick read, but I guess children components can access the same instance right?

Comment: @acmoune If not pass access to the service as a cascading value.

Comment: `OwningComponentBase` fits in some situations, but it's a pretty blunt tool!  See my answer below as to why.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.

There's a problem in the Service Container implementation used by Blazor.  It was designed for server-side rendering.  `Scoped` services match the scope of the page/Http request.  In Blazor that represents the SPA session.  There's no matching scope for a component/page.  `OwningComponentBase` was designed to fit this need, but it's useless in many situations - I explain why further down.

Your options depend on the nature of the service.

##### No `IDisposable/IAsyncDisposable` on Service

If your Service doesn't implement `IDisposable/IAsyncDisposable` you can scope it as `Transient` and then cascade it from the top level page/form.

##### `IDisposable/IAsyncDisposable` on Service

If your Service implements `IDisposable/IAsyncDisposable` you need to use `ActivatorUtilities` to create an instance of the service/object with it's dependancies populated from the service container.  This ensures the service container doesn't retain any references to the instance.  You cascade this as above.  **Important** - You are responsible for the disposal.

Neither of these are perfect.  Cascading an object causes constant *Render Tree Cascades*: it's an object and the Render has no way of detecting changes.

##### `OwningComponentBase`

Any Scoped services that your service depends on are created in the same container: it is after all just a Scoped container. Take AuthenticationService. The instance in the SPA scoped container is the one your service needs, but instead it gets a new one with no user information. The same applies to Notification services, the NavigationManager and many others. It's useless, except in very specific circumstances.

My personal current solution is a `ComponentServiceProvider` service that creates and manages service instances for the component.  It's too lengthy to cover here in detail. There's a repo here: https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.ComponentServiceProvider along with a more detailed discussion of the above.

Comment: It is obvious that you have a lot of experience in this subject. I think the easier solution for newcomers like me is to give `OwningComponentBase` a try, and not try to fix the issues I don't have yet. I hope I will quickly get into a scenario where I need more. I already bookmarked your repo. Thanks.

Comment: @acmoune - np.  Just be aware of it's deficiencies.  It had me pulling my hair out for a while!